# 2d array Stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

I'm getting an error "Run-Time Check Failure #2" for a two dimensional array.

```
char temp[5][100] = {0};
sprintf_s(temp[1], sizeof(temp), "test");
cout << temp[1] << endl;
```

But when the index is zero there is no error.

```
char temp[5][100] = {0};
sprintf_s(temp[0], sizeof(temp), "test");
cout << temp[0] << endl;
```

I do understand what is causing this error.  Can someone enlighten me?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need enough code to reproduce the error.

Comment: sizeof(temp) is the entire array.  If you don't start at [0] it is not the correct value.

Comment: @stark Thank you. That fixed it.